# How to show direct sum of free product of groups is not isomorphic to free product of direct sum of groups?

Tags: group-theory, direct-product, free-product

I guess that $(\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z) *\mathbb Z$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z \times (\mathbb Z *\mathbb Z)$ since there's no such associative law. What I try: we can write these two groups as generators and relations such that $(\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z) *\mathbb Z = \{a,b,c:ab = ba \}$ and $\mathbb Z \times (\mathbb Z *\mathbb Z) = \{a,b,c : abc = bca \}$. They all have 3 generators, and they should be quotient groups of $\mathbb Z * \mathbb Z * \mathbb Z$. But I don't know how to proceed. Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: a "distributive law" would give $(A\times B)*C$ isomorphic to $(A*C)\times (B*C)$. You mean "associative law".

Comment: Yes, edited it.

Comment: I would call it *coproduct* of groups instead of *direct sum*. In any case, I would try to prove that one does not possess the universal property of the other.

Comment: Your presentation of the second group is wrong. $a$ commutes with both $b$ and $c$. The first group has trivial centre and the second one has infinite cyclic centre.

Comment: Another method is to compare the number of homomorphisms from each group to $S_3$ (or any other finite nonabelian group). There are strictly more such homomorphisms from the first group than from the second.